# errors when installing older dplyr package in R

Tags: r, package

Im a bit new to R and need to use/adapt someone else code in R. 
My supervisor uses R version 3.2.2 with the dplyr package version 0.4.3 (to overcome errors and problems with the original code).
I tried to install the older dplyr package with different methods:
- installed devtools package and then used the url devtools::install_url("http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/dplyr/dplyr_0.1.2.tar.gz")
- manual installation (where I downloaded the file and tried to install it.) Installation seemed to have worked but when I run the code it gives a fatal error massage

Every way I've tried so far either gives a lot of error messages or a fatal error and shutdown.

When using help ?dplyr it gives a pop-up that there is an error. Does anybody have any other ideas to install this package?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could be more specific about "lot of error messages"? I'd rather not guess, there are many many errors that could occur here.

Comment: lengths <- summarise(pats_nsaid_diff, length_series = ifelse(FALSE %in% lag_OK, first(which(FALSE == lag_OK)) - 1, n()))           
Error: Unsupported vector type language

Comment: This is the first line of code that provides the error message (unsupported vector type language) when using dplyr 0.5.0. It might be a problem with the "summarise" part?

Comment: Read [help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), then edit your question both with *sample* data, *sample* code, and the errors you get. (Please resist the urge to put code/errors in comments unless truly trivial.)